# hbase get Rows only not null columns(Existing columns using condition)- in hbase table using java

Tags: java, filter, hbase, notnull

In hbase table I have 30 columns.example c1,c2,c3,c4......c30.and cf is column family.
In one row I have c1 to c5 columns
In some row c1,c3,c4,c6 ,c23 like that.
So I want the rows only c2 and c3 are not null ,means these two column must exist in the row .
if I use columnPrefix filter It is working only for one column but not more than one.Which filter can I use.Iam Using hbase 0.98.3 verion

Answer (score 1):

You may want to give a try to MultipleColumnPrefixFilter. Check Below cloudera documentation for use.

http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/latest/topics/admin_hbase_filtering.html

Here is an another link with example.

http://www.hadooptpoint.com/filters-in-hbase-shell/

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But MultipleColumnPrefixFilter is getting matched columns.If I use this filter for two  columns.In that out put rows these two columns not there .Means If row contains these two columns it is working fine.But these two columns are not mandatory in row .sometime one column,some times two columns.So it is giving all the rows whether these two columns not there also(Means atleast one column)

Comment: Ok.got your point. You may try this. 
 scan 'sample',{FILTER=> "(ColumnPrefixFilter('col4')) OR ColumnPrefixFilter('col1')"}
You can use OR operator with ColumnPrefixFilter. If one of them is present then it will return row key.Hope this will help.

Comment: I need to get combination of two columns which should not be null in the row .Means in sql===(select * from emp where sal!=null and comm!=null)==Like that I want in hbase

Comment: do you mean column value should not be null ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.yes the resultset  should contain these records only .

Comment: You may want to try this.  scan 'sample',{COLUMNS => ['samplecolumn1:col4','samplecolumn1:col3'],FILTER => "ValueFilter(!=, 'binary: ' )"}   . In this value filter operator is != and value as your null character (here i have used as space my null character). In Columns parameter you can specify your columns that you want to compare.Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I have used Nullcomparator class  with valueFilter.It worked for me .

Comment: how to store the video files in hbase table.I want to implement in the table.

Comment: can you please tell me how to store video files.When iam storing video file it is saying java.lang.OutOfMemoryError is coming

Comment: @kartik could you please provide the code sample how you used `ValueFilter` and `NotNullComparator` ?